# How to define multer storage in different file?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have a node application with express.
The server is at server.js and I have routers set up like the following:

```
app.use('/xyz', xyz);
app.use('/abc', abc);
```

The routers xyz and abc are in different route modules in `/routes`.
I want to use multer to upload images to MongoDB. The endpoint for uploading files is `/xyz/upload`

```
storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: process.env.DB_URL,
    file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const filename = file.originalname;
        const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
    });
    }
});
```

How can I define this `const upload = multer({ storage });` in the xyz router file?

All the examples on the internet show multer being defined in server.js and app.post(). What to do if I have a router defined in a different module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a cleaner architecture then I would suggest following the separation of concerns principle (SoC) and treat the file handling middleware in a separate file as follows:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(
      null,
      new Date().getTime() + "-" + uniqueSuffix + "-" + file.originalname
    );
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject all files except jpeg
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

module.exports = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 15, // 15mb max size,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
```

then, in your routes, a simple require if you are working with CommonJS should be enough:

```
const upload = require("./fileHandling");

server.post(
    `/route`,
    upload.array('Photos', 6),
    controller,
  );
```

It did the trick for me, hope it helps!

Comment: In which file should I export upload? in server.js?

Comment: Can you give me some kind of a code example, would really help

Comment: Last question, what is the controller in the last line of code?

Comment: You can just ignore it, I am used to add a controller after file uploading to send a response to the server if everything is ok. Hope you find my answer helpful!

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: I´ve made an edit so you can control your upload options in the routes file